# Delphi FMX FormStyle StayOnTop only while app is active

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney

Delphi 10.4 FMX desktop project

I create a form and set its FormStyle to StayOnTop. The window works as expected, staying on top of other windows in the project.

But when the app goes into the background, this form stays on top of all other apps. How do get this window to go into the background like all the other windows in the project?

Comment: Is opening the form with``ShowModal`` an option?

Comment: ShowModal is not the way to go. This is a tool window that should float while allowing other windows to be edited.

Comment: When minimizing the app, hide all tool windows, nd show them again when the app is shown

Comment: The app is not being minimized. It's going into the background. 

I have not been able to find a reliable way in code to detect when an FMX desktop app goes into the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to make OnActivate and OnDeactivate on **MainForm** ? :

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Form2) then
    Form2.FormStyle := TFormStyle.StayOnTop;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Form2) then
    Form2.FormStyle := TFormStyle.Normal;
end;
```